# Reading a specific input and print it in the same format

Tags: c

I am quite newbie in programming and I want to print out a specific input format the exact way as shown below.

```
5 5
1
2 2 0 1
```

---

```
5 5
1
2 2 0 1
```

The top part is the input parameters and the below part which is the same as well is the output. How do I format my `scanf` and `printf` to achieve this format? This is actually a 2D array problem but I believe for this part I would not need a 2D array yet? As for stage 1, I am just suppose to print out this format of inputs.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer is to not use `scanf` but to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead to read the whole lines.

If you then need to use the separate values in the line, then you can use `sscanf` or [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to get them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but I didn't learn all those stuff you mentioned. If i were constraint to just scanf, how do i do it?

Comment: @Morde `scanf` is not really designed to do it, but you could perhaps use the `"%[^"` format (see e.g. [this `scanf` and family reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)).

Comment: @Morde, if you were really constrained to just `scanf`, my answer gives one (pretty ugly) method. But, to be honest, if you were constrained that way, I'd be finding out how to get *unconstrained!*